# call add_filter() when I use update_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have created one custom field in my product form on wordpress(woocommerce) for a checkbox. It saves `yes` `no`. WP admin -> products -> bla bla

for this I wrote this function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field' );
 function wc_custom_save_custom_fields( $post_id) {
          // Save Checkbox

  $checkbox = isset( $_POST['_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
   update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkbox', $checkbox );
}
```

now what I want to do is call `add_filter` when I update checkbox to `yes` or on my website when page loads it needs to check if my `$checkbox` is `'yes'` or `'no'`

here is that function which i want to execute

```
function prefix_dokan_add_review_nav( $url ) {

    unset( $url['reviews'] );
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'dokan_get_dashboard_nav', 'prefix_dokan_add_review_nav' );
```

Any idea how can I do it?

**EDIT**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field' );
 function wc_custom_save_custom_fields( $post_id) {
          // Save Checkbox

  $checkbox = isset( $_POST['_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
   update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkbox', $checkbox );
 if($checkbox == 'yes'){
    add_filter( 'dokan_get_dashboard_nav', 'prefix_dokan_add_review_nav' );
    }
}
```

I have tried doing this but it dont work

Comment: Should be able to add it in the above function. `if $checkbox=='yes' ...`

Comment: @inarilo I have tried doing it but it wont work

Comment: at what point does the filter run? you could also add it as before and inside the filter function add a check for the checkbox value

Comment: @inarilo Could you please check I have updated the question